# Does PostgreSQL Database work on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-server-2012

Can we install PostgreSql database for windows server 2012 R2 ? Do we need any commercial license for redistributing it with our's windows desktop application?

Comment: looks like this is covered in the postgres license: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217161/can-i-make-a-postgresql-redistributable

Comment: What does this have to do with C#, .NET and WPF? Also it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: "*Do we need any commercial license for redistributing*" - no. because it's licensed under the MIT license: http://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/

Comment: Is there some other question behind this? Because the answer should have been obvious from PostgreSQL's site and download page

Comment: [Quote from the FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#What_versions_of_Windows_does_PostgreSQL_run_on.3F): "*PostgreSQL is supported on Windows XP and above, at least as of version 9.0. It will run on 32 and 64 bit systems*"

Comment: I am worried about installation on windows 2012 R2, does it work perfect on windows server 2012 R2 and I found some threads regarding issues on w2012 R2   http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BD0D89EC2438455C9DE0DC94D36912F4@maumau

Comment: The thread you are linking to is about a pretty old Postgres version (and one that goes out of support in about 7 months). The shared memory problems on Windows have long been resolved.

Answer (score 5):

```
Q: Is it supported in Windows Server 2012 R2?
Ans: Yes

Q: Is it free?
Ans: Yes (MIT License)

Q: Does it have unknown issues in the latest Stable release?
Ans: Probably yes. But that is true for any software.

Q: Does it have jarring in-the-face bugs that stand unresolved?
Ans: Probably no.

Q: So should you be considering it effectively stable on Windows Server 2012 R2?
Ans: Yes
```